# Visual Studio solution not able to create a folder named "Server"

Tags: visual-studio

I can't seem to be able to create folder named "Server" in Visual Studio Solution explorer. When I right click Solution -> Add -> New Solution Folder and name the folder "Server" I get following error message.

[Solution Explorer add new folder error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMR6l.png)

Solution Folder names cannot:
- contain any of the following characters: / ? : & ...
- contain Unicode control characters
- be system reserved names, including 'CON', 'AUX', 'PRN'...
Please enter valid name.

Has anyone come across this issues or knows how to fix it? "Server" is a valid folder name. When I use folder name "Server1" it works.

It used to work but suddenly some days back it started giving this issue.

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: It's probably a `system reserved name`.

Comment: It is not. I tried it on another machine where it works.